# how to hide two random label's text among six label?

Tags: iphone, random

I have Six labels, I want to hide two label's text randomly when a button is clicked.I am new to iphone,How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to associate an int to each label using the `tag` property. Then call `viewWithTag` and set the `hidden` property to `YES`. You can generate a random int between `1` and `6` using `int i = (arc4random() % 6)+1;`. To get two different ones, the easiest is just to do the same thing to define `j` until `j` and `i` are different.

Now an example:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed {
    for (int i=1; i<=6; ++i) {
        [[self.view viewWithTag:i] setHidden:NO];
    }
    int i = (arc4random() % 6)+1;
    int j = i;
    while (j==i) {
        j = (arc4random() % 6)+1;
    }
    [[self.view  viewWithTag:i] setHidden:YES];
    [[self.view  viewWithTag:j] setHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: thanks... but it only hide only one label.

Comment: @MUKESH Then you either have a typo or did not define your labels to have tags 1,2,3,4,5,6. This code worked when I tested it.

Answer (score 0):

First select the label you want to hide. For that you could use `viewWithTag:int`. to hide labels you could do one of the following or both.

```
[label setAlpha:0.0];
[label setHidden:YES];
```

Comment: but i want to hide random labels when i click a button.

Comment: ok then what i told is prefect for hiding a lable. If you want to randomise it then try what pengone suggests. If essentially the same with random number thrown in.